# Error with sequelize many to many association using Field attribute

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize v3.11.0  and sails v0.11.0 using MySQL DB.

I have my models/User.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field:'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field:'last_name'
    },
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }
}
```

model/Category.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
    name: {
         type: Sequelize.STRING,
         allowNull:false,
         unique:true,
    },
       description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
   }
}
```

model/UsersCategory.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: { },
    options: {
        tableName: 'user_categories'
    },
    associations: function() {
        User.belongsToMany(Category, {
            through: UsersCategory,
            foreignKey: {
                name:'userId',
                field:'user_id'
            }
        });
        Category.belongsToMany(User, {
            through: UsersCategory,
            foreignKey: {
                name:'categoryId',
                field:'category_id'
            }
        });
    }
};
```

But when I'm executing this code In my database user_categories table I'm geting the attribute as:

> category_id , userId

I'm not getting that why userId in camelcase.

when I'm doing:

```
User.findAll({
    include: [
          {all:true}
        ]
   })
```

I'm getting error:

> "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Categories.UsersCategory.user_id' in 'on clause'"
>
> But If I user userId and CategoryId in my UserCategory model then It working Fine.

Is there is some problem with the Field in many to many association?

Comment: Could you please confirm the Sequelize version you're using? I can't see v0.10 on the releases page (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases). The most recently released version is 3.13.0.

Comment: I'm using the sequelize v3.11.0.

Comment: I think I've repro'ed this problem using MySQL on Sequelize 3.11.0 and 3.13.0 (no Sails). Repro here: https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/tree/master/tests/07-mysql-many-many-error

I'm still looking into it, I need to learn the code that implements underscored. Is this still a problem for you?